# What is optimal way to search Redis keys by prefix?

Tags: redis

For example, I have stored a value under some keys in redis with prefix `doc:`

```
doc:office:room_1
doc:office:room_2
doc:reception
```

Let's say I want to find key prefix `doc:office:`

How can I fastly search keys by prefix beside `KEYS`, `SCAN` command?

I have checked [Redis Search](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/quick_start/), but it works only on fields not on the keys itself.
Can I add index keys somehow?

Comment: did you use the @guyroyse answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could manage an index yourself. For example, you could have a Set called doc:office. Whenever you add or remove a key that starts with doc:office, you could add or remove that string from the Set. Then, if you need all the keys with that prefix, just get the members of the Set.

Like this:

```
> SET doc:office:room_1 data
> SADD doc:office doc:office:room_1

> SET doc:office:room_2 moardata
> SADD doc:office doc:office:room_2

> SMEMBERS doc:office
1) doc:office:room_1
2) doc:office:room_2
```

Comment: Thanks, for response! I can find what would it be time complexity to find by prefix with SET. Could you please help me to figure it out?

Comment: SET and SADD are O(1). If you use SADD variadicly—i.e. to add more than one thing—it is O(N) where N is the number of things you are adding. SMEMBERS is O(N) where N is the cardinality of the Set. You can find detailed descriptions, including the time complexity, of all Redis functions at https://redis.io/commands/.